# How do I send FCM notifications with a specific android notification id?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to be able to cancel notifications that my backend sends to android devices.

On the Android side of things, the [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager) class requires a notification ID to call the cancel(...) method. On the client side, the notification ID for an FCM message is not exposed.

Is there a way on the backend that I can send a message using a specific android notification id?